# Add user with users-admin

Tags: 14.04, users, user-management

I can't seem to get the `users-admin` command to work properly under `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`. When I open it, everything looks fine, but pressing the **Add** button does nothing, no reaction at all. At a minimum, I can't seem to see anything in `/var/log/syslog`, where would I look for errors?

Some items of note:

- This is a headless server, I'm trying to use this GUI in a VNC.
- I'm **not** trying to run this as root, simply: `$ users-admin` as my normal user.
- This VNC is using XFCE.

If this isn't the recommended GUI for user management under XFCE anymore, please give me some recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

If it is anything like 12.04, you must unlock the window first by clicking on the LOCK icon in the upper right corner and entering your password when prompted.  I have long felt the method was needlessly cryptic and I would have hoped they'd have fixed the issue by 14.04.

Comment: Hmm, not seeing anything like that (at least within XFCE) here's a [screenshot of what I'm seeing](http://i5.minus.com/ic7qamL3FKG5y.png).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I stand corrected.  It seems that the cause of your difficulty may be what I'm already coming to learn, namely that 14.04 has numerous bugs and may stand as the most regrettable version to date.  I would advise you to try 12.04LTS, at least it works right.